# issue in displaying Image in laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I had uploaded an image by using the `Intervention` PHP image handling and manipulation library in `laravel4`. By using this library I uploaded the image properly but the problem I facing is that when I tryed to display those image from database, it is showing that there is an invalid url. However, the url is valid and I think this is an issue regarding permissions.

I am posting the below permission that is given by default to an uploading folder and also the user is permitted to access it is www-data.[image]

**My Code**

```
@section('main')
@extends('layouts/user')
<h1>All Users</h1>

<p>{{ link_to_route('users.create', 'Add new user') }}</p>

@if ($users->count())
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->firstName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->lastName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->emailId }}</td>

                    <td>{{ $user->address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ HTML::image('uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') }}</td>

                    </td>

                    <td>{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit',
                            array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                    {{ Form::open(array('method' 
                            => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id))) }}                       
                                                        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class'
                            => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>

    </table>
            <div class="pagination"><?php echo $users->links(); ?></div>
@else
    There are no users
@endif

@stop
```

Comment: just displaying it on local host

Comment: Show us the code you are using to display the image, and `var_dump` the image url

Comment: did you check your .htaccess file if there is one?

Comment: yes there is .htaccess file

Comment: why don't you save images into app/storages

Comment: please provide your local url

Comment: Also check your console to see the error : 403 will means it is a permission issue, 404 will means it's a bad url or the file is missing, ...

Comment: it is permission issue but how to give permission to a folder who is owner as  www-data. because i tried chmod 777 -R to the folder path but it is not taking  permissions

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. An url like `http://localhost/testLara/uploadimg/image.jpg` should work

Comment: ya i gave the path but no success i post my code so you will come to know

Comment: please check now i had posted the code

Comment: What does `{{ HTML::image('uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') }}` outputs ?

Comment: @Brewel it outputs <img src="http://localhost/testLara/uploadImage/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg">

Comment: @Ricky: it appears that is your problem. It should be `http://localhost...`. I tried tracking this down for you but Laravel is such a quaqumire of loosely linked classes, I had to give up. It comes from URLGnerator which uses the symphony Request class for the protocol (isSecure)...

Comment: @Robbie thanks for the reply but still no success .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check what error you are getting when you displaying the image from from browser directly.(I mean enter the full URL to the image on browser).
2. Make sure the URL generated by laravel and the real image URL are same. if you can display the image from browser directly.
3. All the images should be in public folder and normally should not have an .htacces file in the base.(I mean the folder below public)
4. Make sure .htaccess ile in the public folder is like this,

   ```
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           Options -MultiViews
           RewriteEngine On

           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
       </IfModule>
   ```

Comment: It works the only problem that i facing is of .htaccess file code now it is working properly thanks @Fasil kk

Comment: my previous code was like this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
 RewriteEngine On
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­d
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­f
 
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Any images you create / upload need to go after public/ (or whatever your public folder is) otherwise it will not render to a valid url, since the request will always be to path-to-public-folder/image-folder/image.jpg or something and according to the folder structure in your image, the image-folder is unreachable.

In your case, you created a folder uploadimg in the same level with app directory, while it should be at public/uploadimg

Another thing i notice is that you ask for an image from

```
 {{ HTML::image('uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') }}
```

while it should be from

```
 {{ HTML::image('uploadimg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') }}
```

(assuming the image name and path is correct, this would work if the uploadimg folder is inside public/ folder)

Comment: yes the upload folder is in public itself but i think there is big issue of permission.

Comment: @alou , I think you are incorrect about the "Another thing" part, the capitalization is correct, Ubuntu just uses a funny font. However, I think your first point is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, perhapse, path to the image. 
The root directory for laravel application is app/ directory.

Try to puth apsolute path:
`HTML::image('/var/www/testLara/uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg')`.

And you should store your images in some subdirectory of `/public` directory.

Comment: i dis-agree for the path that you had given inHTML::image('/var/www/testLara/uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') because when we use HTML::image('') it takes path of out base url itself so there is no need to gave full path there unless it get invalid url

Comment: from your code it will generate html like this <img src="http://localhost/testLara/var/www/testLara/uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg"> and it is invalid for url

Comment: Oh, you're right, my mistake.

Anyway, I think you should move `uploadImage` in `/public` directory. 
Also, on Ubuntu (and other Linux distros) `uploadImg` and `uploadimg` are two different directories. So rename you directory or change name in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your "uploadImg" directory is not inside the "public" directory, as others have said, this is according to your screenshot. 
Is there another uploadImg directory inside "public"?
There are three very important questions that remain unanswered.

1. What path does your database show in the table?
2. What does `{{ HTML::image('uploadImg/B05BgJ_school-uniform.jpg') }}` output?
3. Where is the actual image file located, once uploaded? (go check now)